# Get image from gallery iOS?

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I created a factory to get image from gallery on iOS. Now, I'm testing this factory on emulator(simulator) of iOS and it throws an exception. How I haven't any iOS device to test I want know if this factory only works with device or if it's there a problem with this factory. On Android this factory works fine.

**factory**

```
var app = angular.module('starter');

app.factory('CameraFactory', ['$q', function($q) {

    var options = {
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: 0,      // 0:Photo Library, 1=Camera, 2=Saved Photo Album        
    }

    return {
        getPicture: function(callback){
            var onSuccess = function(imageData) {
                window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imageData, function(fileEntry) {
                    if (callback) callback({ 
                              success:true,
                              path: fileEntry.nativeURL, 
                              imageData: imageData 
                            });
                });

            };

            var onFail = function(e) {
                console.log("onFail! " + e);
                if (callback) callback( {success:false} );
            };
            navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, options);
        }
    }
}]);
```

**Exception**

```
1     706110   error    Error: Can't find variable: Camera
http://192.225.162.87:8100/js/factories/CameraFactory.js:7:32
```

Line 7 has: `Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI`

Comment: Have you installed the plugin ? You should try ngCordova to combine cordova with angularJs

Comment: @SmileApplications yes, I have. How I said before on Android works fine.

Comment: Maybe you have it on Android and not on iOS.. Try cordova plugin list ios and check if it is there

Comment: @SmileApplications I think this only works on device. Look this text: `The camera is not available in the iPhone Simulator. Test with the Photo Album when running in the iPhone Simulator, and test the camera on an actual iPhone device.`

Comment: Ok you solved it 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @FernandoPaiva stated in the comments, The emulator does not support the API you are trying to access as it doesn't actually have a camera. You can see this noted in the documentation I have linked below.

`NOTE: The camera API only works on a real device, and not in the emulator.`

http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/camera/